# mapping Xbox elite v2 underside buttons

Tags: 19.10, xbox-one, xbox-elite-controller

The underside buttons are by default mapped like so;
(A) and (X) will be in your left hand and (B) and (Y) will be in your right hand :
[image: xbox elite underside button mappings]

I would like to map P4 to LB and P2 to RB, and why not P1 to Y while P3 will be mapped to B.

Comment: You have tagged a EOL and thus off-topic release - http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: wrong one I meant 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution One :

Is booting to a real windows, and adding the xbox accessories app from the microsoft store. this will require a live/outlook/hotmail email to use.

I happen to have one. Make sure to keep selecting the "hidden" option such as "no thanks" or "use account only for microsoft apps" to prevent microsoft attempting to switch your windows to email authentication/account...

from there it's pretty straightforward. The profiles you make belong to and are stored on, the device, so they continue to exist on ubuntu (all three of them). I am looking into an ubuntu-only solution :

[image: xbox controller configuration]